# jquery remember opened list items

Tags: jquery, cookies, drop-down-menu, save, state

I want to figure out a menu state remember via jquery and cookie.

I'm using jQuery-cookie.js, but I still have no clue how could I do it well.

I've took a try based on this article:
http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-simple-vertical-accordion-menu-with-cookies/

The problem with it, that this remembers only one menu item's state. But I have a multilevel dropdown and I want to save each menu item's (via class "active" ) state.

Could anyone let me some solution or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if the parents of the menu require a 'active' class too you might want to make a function to add those. Then you should save the DOM-objects of the menu-items who have the 'active' class. With the DOM you can add them once again